# Javascript Vector Rotations

Tags: javascript, vector

I have the following:

```
function Vec2(x, y) {
this.x = x;
this.y = y;
}

Vec2.prototype.rotate = function(d) {
var x = this.x;
var y = this.y;
this.x = x * Math.cos(d) + y * Math.sin(d);
this.y = y * Math.cos(d) - x * Math.sin(d);
}

var v = new Vec2(0, 1);
```

And after:

```
v.rotate(90);
```

The vector should be 1, 0 (or -1, 0?), but this returns 0.8939966636005579, -0.4480736161291702.

Why is this?

Comment: the `d` should be converted to radian (not deg) first?

Comment: I tried that with my radInDeg() function in the rotate bit, but it still had wrong values, plus I am 90% sure that this equation uses degrees.

Comment: the argument passed in is `90deg`, you have to convert that `90deg` to the corresponding radian value (`Math.PI/2`), not sure how you use the `radInDeg`

Comment: Math.cos() and Math.sin() both use radians.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a toRad function and then use it on 'd'.

```
function toRad(Value) {
    return Value * Math.PI / 180;
}

Vec2.prototype.rotate = function(d) {
d = toRad(d);
var x = this.x;
var y = this.y;
this.x = x * Math.cos(d) - y * Math.sin(d);
this.y = y * Math.cos(d) + x * Math.sin(d);
}
```

Your function is also using the wrong equations, which are in the function I posted.

Comment: Yes, that is my radInDeg(), but it does not help.

Comment: that now returns: 1, 6.123233995736766e-17

Comment: @user3786755 looks like it's the matter of rounding, that value is almost close to `0`.

Comment: And it should be (-1, 0). Look at my edit to fix your equations.

Comment: I just added a Math.round(), because I think it _was_ rounding, plus I copied the equation from a messy sheet of paper so thank you.